# CASE with INTERSECT in a SQL SELECT

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with a column being an array:

```
id | name | keywords
1  | test | {1,2,4}
2  | t3st | {1}
3  | te5t | {3}
4  | t35t | {}
```

I'd like to get in a SELECT request a column telling me if an array intersects the "keywords" column array. For example, if I look for keywords {2,3}, I'd like to have this:

```
id | name | keywords | match
1  | test | {1,2,4}  | true
2  | t3st | {1}      | false
3  | te5t | {3}      | true
4  | t35t | {}       | false
```

I found "CASE" which could help me creating this new column, but I struggle using "INTERSECT", because I think I may want to check if the INTERSTECTION is NOT NULL.

Any help would be great, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`&&`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html) operator is an array overlap operator.  You don't need a `case` expression, you can simply use:

```
select t.*, (keywords && :input_array) as match
from t;
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. I didn't know this operator, thanks for the hint, now I think I have some old queries to optimize...

Comment: @djcaesar9114 . . . If you are using arrays, it is worth reading the documentation pointed to in the answer.  You may not *remember* the particular syntax.  But you'll have a vague aware that "Hey, Postgres probably does this" and know where to look.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm on it right now. Very useful, I've got some reading these next few days :)